# How do I set defaults (like environment) in Pakyow?

Tags: pakyow

Total newbie question... There is a lot in the documentation about how to configure behavior for a given environment. And the output from `pakyow help server` indicates that the environment can be set to something other than the default. But how (and where) are such defaults set? Should this be done via `app.default_environment`, and if so, where would that go? The `configure` block in `app/setup.rb`?

Note that I'll be happy to submit an update to the docs that adds the answer to this question.

Comment: Do you mean starting the server in `development`, `prototype`, `production`, etc?

Comment: @bryanp no, I know how to do that from help, I mean changing the default; I had thought that might be what the `.env` file is for, but I can't find documentation about that...

Comment: Best practice is to pass the environment you want when using `pakyow server` (e.g. `pakyow server production`) or set the `RACK_ENV` environment variable and start with `rackup` (e.g. `RACK_ENV=production rackup`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the server in a given mode, say development

Just do

`bundle exec pakyow server 'development'`

https://www.pakyow.org/docs/tools

From my understanding, the default environment can be set on the app object in a configure block in setup.rb

`app.default_environment (development)`

This configuration option is used to set the default environment.
The environment you set using the `app.default_environment` specifies the mode the server the defaults to.

Here's an example of a configure block.

```
configure :development do
  # put your development config here
end
```

And for production replace `:development` with `:production`

Here's an example for how you would set the default environment

`Pakyow::App.define do
  configure do
    app.default_environment = :test
  end
end`

If you do not specify which environment to use as the default, it defaults to `:development`.

App is just one of the things you can configure to find out how to configure other things, such as Server, Logger, Presenter, Realtime refer to the Docs here at https://www.pakyow.org/docs/config

Environment variables can be set in the .env file

Example .env file contents

`SESSION_SECRET=8ac762ca808a8f3151b69d53fc6e2f5efbe46926472695a7cf23514c29cb5ce19ae434e80c96caac1009754cda605c678dba602608708e886447f7b059567645`

`REDIS_URL=redis://127.0.0.1:6379`

The environment variables can be accessed like this in setup.rb

`ENV['REDIS_URL']`

And you can set it to the variable like so

`redis_url = ENV['REDIS_URL']`

or you set it to the app object like so for it to be available anywhere in the project

`app.redis = ENV['REDIS_URL']`

And you can now access the the environment variable anywhere in the project by doing this

`Pakyow::Config.app.redis`

Hope that helps!

Comment: So is there any way to change, for example, what the default start mode is for the server, or do you have to specify the mode at launch? It seems silly to me that on a production server, for example, you couldn't change the default.

Comment: I think that's what the `app.default_environment` is for. If you set it there then that's the mode the server is going to start in

Comment: Hmmm... setting `app.default_environment` appears to do nothing. That is, if I set this, regardless of the value (`:production`, for example), the `:development` configure block is executed. Ideas?

Comment: Aha! Turns out it's a bug in the version that I'm using. Thanks for the help! I'll post more about my use case when I'm finished.